# unique random string in MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to generate a random 3 digit string in MVC3-Razor-C#.net. But condition is that, before generating random string, i need to check in database i.e. SQL 2008 whether this record is already present or not. If the random generated string is already present in database I need to generate new string. This functionality is for a button called "NextAvailable". I was able to generate random string using JavaScript, but not able to check in database if it is already exists. It would be great if any help me out for this.

```
Here is my Javascript function which is working fine, but how to check database using AJAX for existence of a string.

 function btnNextAvailable_OnClick() {
  $("#nextAvailableButtonClick.val('true')");
  var chars = "0123456789";
  var stringLength = 3;
  var randomstring = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
  var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("SequentialId").value = randomstring
  }
```

Comment: Send generated string via ajax to server, server will check if there's any and return respective data. If server returns that data exists call repeat from regeneration until server returns that data is new. But better would be to generate random string on server so you can avoid not needed requests from client.

Comment: I agree with @PLB. Prior to returning the information back to user, that is, before rendering the page, generate a three digit string that does not exist in the database and return it in a hidden field or put it in a session or cookie and then return it to user. Even better store it in a database with a flag that signals that it is not yet used.

Comment: I agree that @CodeCaster's solution below is the correct way forward - get your database to generate the first random number that is not in the table - Be aware, though, that this will only leave you a maximum 1,000 possible combinations (taking into account that 000 is a valid option). Don't generate it on every page load as it may not be required unless the user submits, therefore you'll save CPU time by only generating and checking the number when actually required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

MVC:

```
public class RandomNumberController : Controller 
                 // Or take a look at ApiController
{
    public ActionResult GetRandomNumber()
    {
        string number = new RandomNumberGenerator().GetNextFreeRandomNumber();
        return Json(new { number = number}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Database logic:

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    public string GetNextFreeRandomNumber()
    {
        // do database calls, return next free random number            
        return "042";
    }
}
```

Now from your webpage, you can do something like this:

```
$.get('/RandomNumber/GetRandomNumber', function(data) {
    alert(data.number);
});
```

You simply do not want your client to keep hammering the service until the service returns a valid number, so you do the number generation on the server.

Now if you have a problem implementing a specific part of this, feel free to update your question.